# How do I make VSCODE understand source maps for concatenated coffeescript files?

Tags: visual-studio-code, coffeescript, gruntjs, vscode-debugger, source-maps

Trying to use the VSCODE debugger on some coffeescript but part of the build process has grunt-contrib-coffee concatenate a bunch of the sources then compile it and create source maps.

ie Gruntfile:
`"staging/public/scripts/controllers/adminControllers.js" : ["app/scripts/controllers/controllerModule.coffee", "app/scripts/controllers/menuController.coffee", "app/scripts/controllers/**/*.coffee"]`

Ends up with all the coffee sources compiled into

- staging/public/scripts/controllers/adminControllers.js
- staging/public/scripts/controllers/adminControllers.js.map
- staging/public/scripts/controllers/adminControllers.src.coffee

I've got my launch.json set with sourceMaps: true and outFiles pointed at the staging directory.

```
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "dev",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/staging/index.js",
            "preLaunchTask": "grunt dev",
            "env": {
                "NODE_ENV": "devel"
              },
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "smartStep": true,
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**/*.js",
                "${workspaceFolder}/staging/**/*.js",
                "!**/node_modules/**"
            ]
        }
```

It picks up the non-concatenated sources/maps just fine but ones such as menuController.coffee are left with the sadness of unresolved breakpoints. Presumably because there is nothing mapping menuController.coffee to adminControllers.js.

I've tried NOT concatenating them but that just breaks everything(of course it does).

I've attempted using grunt-contrib-concat to concatenate the coffee first and include sourceMaps there but the coffeescript compiler does not like it.

```
Running "coffee:compileDev" (coffee) task
>> staging/public/scripts/controllers/adminControllers.coffee:11228:1: error: unexpected //
>> //# sourceMappingURL=adminControllers.coffee.map
>> ^^
>> In file: staging/public/scripts/controllers/adminControllers.coffee
>> On line: 11227
>> //# sourceMappingURL=adminControllers.coffee.map
>> ^
Warning: CoffeeScript failed to compile. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

Couldn't find any grunt-contrib-concat docs for excluding the sourceMappingURL.

I will mention that the Chrome debugger does recognize the source maps and relates adminController.js to adminController.coffee, so that part at least works. It just knows nothing about menuController.coffee or any other individual source file.

**In summary**:
How does one tell VSCODE that sources A.coffee and B.coffee are concatenated to AB.coffee and compiled to AB.js with AB.js.map? Or am I missing the mark entirely in my efforts to step debug my coffeescript?

Comment: transpile the source files and generate individual `map.js` files, do not grunt, this is dev build, prod build is to also grunt

Comment: and then somehow put hundreds of script tags in my html template? Is that a common practice?

Comment: how do you debug this grunted code in other debuggers

Comment: I just recently inherited this project so I don't have other methods. Currently I have to debug in Chrome to step through any code that has been concatenated. There are some coffeescript files that get compiled 1:1 with javascript and the VSC debugger can identify those.